# Merge 2 SQL Queries/Tables

Tags: mysql

I spent so much time googling today but i don't even know which keywords to use. So …

The project is an evaluation of a betting game (Football). I have 2 SQL Queries:

```
SELECT players.username, players.userid, matchdays.userid, matchdays.points, SUM(points) AS gesamt
FROM players INNER JOIN matchdays ON players.userid = matchdays.userid AND matchdays.season_id=5
            GROUP BY players.username
            ORDER BY gesamt DESC
```

And my second query:

```
SELECT max(matchday) as lastmd, points, players.username from players INNER JOIN matchdays ON players.userid = matchdays.userid WHERE matchdays.season_id=5 AND matchday=
 (select max(matchday) from matchdays)group by players.username ORDER BY points DESC
```

The first one adds up the points of every matchday and shows the sum.
The second shows the points of the last gameday.

My Goal is to merge those 2 queries/tables so that the output is a table like

Rank | Username | Points last gameday | Overall points |

I don't even know where to start or what to look for. Any help would be appreciated ;)

Comment: probably someone needs to put an `@variable` (ie `set @rownum:=1`) join together for you. So perhaps search on mysql rownum

Comment: So the second query gets the data for the last matchday in the table. Some players may have data for that day and others not. Yes? And what is the matchdays table's natural unique key? Is there one entry per user and matchday? Or can there be more entries per user and day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation, i.e. sum the points only when the day is the last day:

```
SELECT 
  p.username, 
  SUM(case when m.matchday = (select max(matchday) from matchdays) then m.points end)
    AS last_day_points,
  SUM(m.points) AS total_points
FROM players p
INNER JOIN matchdays m ON p.userid = m.userid AND m.season_id = 5
GROUP BY p.userid
ORDER BY total_points DESC;
```

Or with a join instead of a non-correlated subquery (MySQL *should* come to the same execution plan):

```
SELECT 
  p.username, 
  SUM(case when m.matchday = last_day.matchday then m.points end) AS last_day_points,
  SUM(m.points) AS total_points
FROM players p
INNER JOIN matchdays m ON p.userid = m.userid AND m.season_id = 5
CROSS JOIN
(
  select max(matchday) as matchday
  from matchdays
) last_day
GROUP BY p.userid
ORDER BY total_points DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

use both query with join....use inner join if each userid have value in 2nd query also.also add userid in 2nd query also for join

```
    SET @rank = 0;

    SELECT  @rank := rank + 1,
                t1.username,
                t2.points,
                t1.gesamt
    FROM        (
                    SELECT  players.username, players.userid puserid, matchdays.userid muserid, matchdays.points, SUM(points) AS gesamt
                    FROM        players INNER JOIN matchdays ON players.userid = matchdays.userid AND matchdays.season_id=5
                 GROUP BY players.username           
              )t1
              INNER JOIN 
              ( 
                SELECT players.userid, max(matchday) as lastmd, points, players.username 
                    from players INNER JOIN matchdays ON players.userid = matchdays.userid 
                    WHERE matchdays.season_id=5 AND matchday=
                    (select max(matchday) from matchdays)group by players.username
                )t2
                ON t1.puserid = t2.userid
    ORDER BY t1.gesamt
```